# Ideal way to work on new interface for web app on zend framework while leaving original in place?

Tags: svn, zend-framework, web-applications, user-interface

I have a web app which is built with Zend Framework and I'd like to begin working on a new interface. The interface work will be mostly CSS and some jQuery. Lets say my project folder is `/var/www/application`

I'm not using SVN at the moment but I would like to setup a repository for my new interface files. I've installed trac before and i'm familiar with SVN basics. I'd like to only use SVN for this new interface CSS work just to get the hang of SVN.

Is there a way I can use my current zend framework project, and work on a new interface at the same time, if so how?

If not should I rsync a copy of the production server to a development server and begin replacing all the CSS, jQuery and whatever else then rsync it back to production server once the design work is completed?

Or do I turn my `/var/www/application` into my repository trunk, branch off it for my CSS work then commit which seems like the proper way but again i'm new to SVN, and rather only use it for minor work before doing something I can't undo.

Thanks

Comment: Do your dev work on your dev server, never on your production server.

Answer (score 0):

In order to work on a new design, you don't really have to involve version control. That being said, I think version control is always a good thing to be using on any project. While we are at it, I would advise you to try either Git (recommended) or at least Mercurial.

If you application is setup to use modules, simply copy your current module to a new module and modify the new module's view scripts to use the updated css/javascript.

There are cleaner way to do this with helpers and other tools in the framework; however, this is the most pragmatic and easy to understand way (albeit a bit heavy handed).